# Pip install error not on correct version of Python

Tags: python, pip

[image]

I'm trying to install Pandas through `pip install` on `python 3.8` but the terminal tries to use the `pip` from `python 3.9` on my computer, though I had thought I deleted everything from the `python 3.9` folder. For reference, `3.8` and `3.9` look like this:

[image]

[image]

Under `Python3.9/Scripts`, there is a pip installer for `python 3.9`. If I just delete the `lib` and `scripts` folder from `python 3.9`, will the pip installer automatically default to `3.8`?

Thanks

Comment: In general it is better to use `$ python -m pip` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue, I just had to delete the entire python3.9 folder containing lib and script.

Comment: Answer used instead of the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The short approach, remove python3.9 from your Windows Env Variables.

The best approach is using VirtualENV with the custom Python version.

1.- install [VirtualEnv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html)
2.- Create an ENV in your terminal with your specific Python version.

> virtualenv venv -p=/c/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe

3.- Activate your VirtualEnv with

> source venv activate

Now you have your installation isolated.

Comment: would it just be better to completely uninstall Python 3.9 from my system? For some reason, there is no python executable file under 3.9, just the folders of Lib and Script, but I can still access the 3.9 shell from the Windows Search Bar.